# Photoshop Extendscript: How to var check currently opened files and execute commands for certain filenames

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I have several images opened at once in photoshop but they need to be checked accordingly with the filename and saved out accordingly. Thanks!

Example:

Name.SizexSize.png -> add 1px border -> JPG 59kb -> Save for web + no prompt. Name.SizexSize.png -> add 1px border -> JPG 39kb -> Save for web + no prompt. Overwrite originals. 
isplayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

```
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

if ((documents.length > 0) && (activeDocument.saved)){

var AD = activeDocument;
var initialFolder = activeDocument.path;

var docRef = activeDocument;

    var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
    fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
    if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
        fileNameNoExtension.length--;
    }
    fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");

var Filename = fileNameNoExtension; 

  AD.flatten();
  var docWidth = AD.width; 
  var docHeight = AD.height;
  var docRes = AD.resolution;


  var jpgOptns = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgOptns.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgOptns.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgOptns.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgOptns = new JPEGSaveOptions;

  for(a=0+1;a<=5;a++){

    jpgSaveFile =  File(initialFolder+"/"+Filename+a+".jpg");
    jpgOptns.quality = 5;
AD.saveAs (jpgSaveFile ,jpgOptns , true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

  }

 while (app.documents.length) {
 app.activeDocument.close()
 }

  if(docWidth>docHeight){
  var multipW=1;
  var multipH=13;
  }else{
  var multipW=13;
  var multipH=1;
  }


 }else{

  alert("Either you have no document open or you haven't saved your 
  work anywhere prior to the script \nSave your document first !");

}
```

Comment: What did you try already? What exactly you need help with? Or you expect the whole script will be written for you?

Comment: lol of course not. I need to be able to check each file thats currently opened in photoshop with SizexSize then proceed with export settings. I've tried the following here:

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy code added. ;). I Suppose i need to check the string value of FIlename with all currently open documents in photoshop. Would I need to assign this value to an array instead? If Filename == 300x600 then saveforweb 59kb

Answer (score 0):

To work on opened documents, loop through `documents` object, to get size from the name, I guess something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
  activeDocument = documents[i]; //will change active document to one of the opened

  var docNameSize = activeDocument.name.split(".")[1].split("x"); //will get you [Size, Size] from Name.SizexSize.png;
  for (var k = 0; k < docNameSize.length; k++) docNameSize[k] = parseInt(docNameSize[k]); //will convert [Size, Size] to numbers
}
```

How do you want to add this 1px border? I guess you can do something like that: select all, contract selection, fill with white.

```
selectAll()
contractSelection(1)
invertSelection()
fillWithWhiteColor()
deselect()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function cTID(s)
{
    return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
};

function sTID(s)
{
    return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
};

function selectAll()
{
    var desc26 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref2 = new ActionReference();
    ref2.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), cTID('fsel')); 
    desc26.putReference(cTID('null'), ref2);
    desc26.putEnumerated(cTID('T   '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Al  '));
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc26, DialogModes.NO);
}

function contractSelection(_value)
{
    var desc30 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc30.putUnitDouble(cTID('By  '), cTID('#Pxl'), _value);
    desc30.putBoolean(sTID('selectionModifyEffectAtCanvasBounds'), true);
    executeAction(cTID('Cntc'), desc30, DialogModes.NO);
};

function invertSelection()
{
    executeAction(cTID('Invs'), undefined, DialogModes.NO);
};

function fillWithWhiteColor()
{
    var desc35 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc35.putEnumerated(cTID('Usng'), cTID('FlCn'), cTID('Clr '));
    var desc36 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc36.putUnitDouble(cTID('H   '), cTID('#Ang'), 0.000000);
    desc36.putDouble(cTID('Strt'), 0.000000);
    desc36.putDouble(cTID('Brgh'), 100.000000);
    desc35.putObject(cTID('Clr '), cTID('HSBC'), desc36);
    desc35.putUnitDouble(cTID('Opct'), cTID('#Prc'), 100.000000);
    desc35.putEnumerated(cTID('Md  '), cTID('BlnM'), cTID('Nrml'));
    executeAction(cTID('Fl  '), desc35, DialogModes.NO);
};

function deselect()
{
    var desc38 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref3 = new ActionReference();
    ref3.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), cTID('fsel'));
    desc38.putReference(cTID('null'), ref3);
    desc38.putEnumerated(cTID('T   '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('None'));
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc38, DialogModes.NO);
};
```

And there's no way to specify max size for save for web, but you can use something like this: it'll save a jpg with desired quality (75 by default) and will see if the size is smaller that needed. If it's larger, it'll save again with smaller quality in recursion:

```
saveJPG(
{
    path: activeDocument.path,
    maxSize: 50 //size in kbs
})

function saveJPG(_data)
{
    if (_data.path == undefined) return false;
    _data.name = _data.name == undefined ? activeDocument.name : _data.name;
    _data.quality == undefined && _data.quality = 75;

    if (!new Folder(_data.path).exists)
    {
        alert("Output path doesn't exist!"); //you can add a function to create a path if needed
        return false
    }

    var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(),
        jpgFile = new File(_data.path + '/' + getName(_data.name) + '.jpg');

    options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
    options.quality = _data.quality;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(jpgFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);

    if (_data.maxSize != undefined)
    {
        var ms = _data.maxSize * 1000;
        if (jpgFile.length > ms)
        {
            if (!jpgFile.remove())
            {
                alert('Save file is locked, please make sure it\'s not opened anywhere');
                return
            };
            saveJPG(
            {
                path: _data.path,
                name: _data.name,
                maxSize: _data.maxSize,
                quality: _data.quality - 2
            });
        }
    };

    function getName(fullName)
    {
        var temp = String(fullName).split("/"),
            fullName = temp.pop();
        return fullName.replace(/\.[^.]+$/g, "")
    };
};
```

Comment: IMPRESSIVE! :) thank you!!. this is extremely helpful and will help me develop the correct syntax to learn further. I don't quite understand how you went about specifying the color white through rgbh values. How would I make it so that it would be black instead?

script only works with one image that is opened at a time. it seems to lock up with more than one file open. 
Would it be possible to run it with lets say 5 opened and run through them?

Comment: I made a mistake in the original script: it had both for loops with `i` variable, I think it should work now. In the `fillWithWhiteColor()` color is set via HSB, to have it black use `0`, `0` and `0` values. This code is from ScriptListener plugin that converts photoshop commands to executable AM code (http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/photoshop-script-listener.html)

Comment: Script works great!! Except it only processes the first image. :(. when i try to change the values from desc36.putDouble(cTID('Brgh'), 100.000000);  100 to 000 it errors out. Is their a debug window on this thing?! lol.

Comment: to me it works on all opened documents. I don't know what modifications you did, maybe they cause the script not working on everything.